# WordPress: How can I overwrite php files included in the parent theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wp site with the following directory structure.
Directory structure:

```
themes
 |-parent-theme
 |  |-index.php
 |  |-some-footer.php
 |
 |-parent-theme-child
    |-some-footer.php
```

The parent-theme directory contains a bunch of php files and index.php is one of them. 
The index.php file uses(includes) some-footer.php.

```
<?php include('some_footer.php'); ?>
```

I am trying to overwrite this some-footer.php by create a file with the exact same name, but it is not working.

What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is in a child theme, try using [get_stylesheet_directory_uri();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

```
<?php include( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/some_footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean replacing the line <?php include('some_footer.php'); ?> with the one you suggested?